# NullPointerException en JUnit5

Tags: java, spring, test, junit

Estoy tratando de testear unos métodos crud en Spring, y me sale siempre un error en todos los test de NullPointerException en el Partido p por mucho que lo instancie (tanto con el constructor vacío como con los atributos). He instanciado el partido dentro de la clase, dentro de ambos Before, dentro de cada método... y siempre lo mismo. También con el servicio de Partido donde se encuentran los métodos que quiero testear.

Esta es mi clase de JUnit hasta ahora

```
class TuVotoCuentaTest {
Partido p = new Partido();
PartidoService servicio= new PartidoService();
Set<Partido> listaPartidos = new HashSet<Partido>();

@BeforeAll
static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterAll
static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {



}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws Exception {

}

@Test
public void testAgregar() {

    servicio.save(p);

    Iterable<Partido> resultadoEsperado = servicio.findAll();

    assertNotNull(resultadoEsperado);

}

@Test
public void testEliminar() {

    servicio.delete(p);
    Iterable<Partido> resultadoEsperado = servicio.findAll();
    assertNull(resultadoEsperado);

}



}
```

Y este mi método servicio

```
 @Service
public class PartidoService {
@Autowired
PartidoRepository repositorio;

public Iterable<Partido> findAll() {
    return repositorio.findAll();
}

public Partido findOne(Long id) {
    return (Partido) repositorio.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

public Partido save(Partido p) {
    return repositorio.save(p);
}

public Partido edit(Partido p) {
    return repositorio.save(p);
}

public Partido delete(Partido p) {
    Partido aBorrar = repositorio.findById(p.getId_partido()).orElse(null);
    if (aBorrar != null)
        repositorio.delete(p);

    return aBorrar;
}

public List<Partido> findAllProducts() {
    return repositorio.findAll();
}

public List<Partido> findByNombre(String nombre){
    return repositorio.findByNombreContainingIgnoreCase(nombre);
}

public Partido findByNombreUnPartido(String nombre) {
    return repositorio.findByNombre(nombre);
}

public Partido findByAbreviatura(String abreviatura) {
    return repositorio.findPartidoByAbreviatura(abreviatura);
}
```

}

Y este el error que me salta:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.salesianostriana.tuvotocuenta.services.PartidoService.save(PartidoService.java:27)
at com.salesianostriana.tuvotocuenta.TuVotoCuentaTest.testAgregar(TuVotoCuentaTest.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

UPDATE:

Interfaz PartidoRepository:

```
    public interface PartidoRepository extends JpaRepository <Partido, Long>{



@Query ("select p from Partido p where abreviatura LIKE ?1")
public Partido findPartidoByAbreviatura(String abreviatura);

public  List<Partido> findByNombreContainingIgnoreCase(String nombre);

public Partido findByNombre(String nombre);
```

}

Comment: Es el repositorio el que es nulo.

Comment: respositorio es una interfaz, no puedo instanciarla

Comment: Tendras que instanciar (inyectar) una implementación suya, si no el programa no va a funcionar nunca.

Comment: esa implementación es el servicio que está instanciado

Comment: No se si te he entendido bien. ¿Dices que PartidoService es la implementacion de PartidoRepositorio?

Comment: Exacto, si lo ves, tiene autowireado el repositorio

Comment: Pero es que eso no tiene ningún sentido. Estas inyectando una interfaz a su implementación.

Comment: Tienes razón, fallo mío al expresarme, servicio no implementa al repositorio, tiene el autowired hecho

Comment: ¿Entonces que inyectas a repositorio?

Comment: He hecho update poniendo la clase del servicio entera y el repositorio, de hecho así lo tengo con otras clases y el programa funciona perfectamente

Comment: Vamos a ver, si no inyectas nada a repositorio no puede funcionar porque repositorio no va a valer nada nunca.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que en tu clase de test estás haciendo

```
PartidoService servicio= new PartidoService();
```

Al hacerlo de esta manera, te estás saltando toda la inicialización que hace Spring, motivo por el que el @Autowired que tienes en tu servicio no sirve de nada, el repositorio no se instancia con nada y, por tanto, te provoca un NullPointerException.

Para que te funcione correctamente, ese servicio también debes delegar su inyección en Spring y asegurarte, obviamente, que las pruebas se ejecutan levantando un contexto de Spring. Si no, ese servicio también será nulo.

Comment: Estás diciendo entonces que haga @Autowired al servicio en el test no? si es eso, también lo estoy haciendo y me salta el mismo error

Comment: Entonces, por lo que dices, no estás ejecutando los test en un contexto de Spring y, por tanto, nadie sabe cómo interpretar esos @Autowired. Revísate la documentación de Spring para testing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html